# How to Bind selected Item values of MenuFlyoutItem to another page?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I have a ListView, in that individual each ListViewItem has a MenuFlyOutItem of same names. But when I Click that name in MenuFlyOutItem which is in ListViewItem has to navigate to next page along with that selected item from MenuFlyouItem  of ListViewItem.
Please find the file I have attached.

XAML Code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,15,0" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Blue" Height="50" Width="15">
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem >
                            <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuFlyoutItem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <SymbolIcon Margin="10,10,10,10" Symbol="Map"></SymbolIcon>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="10,10,10,10" Text="Geo Tag" FontSize="20" ></TextBlock>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                        </MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Create Notification" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Background="Transparent" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Statistics" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Background="Transparent"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="History" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Background="Transparent"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Orders" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Background="Transparent"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Inspection Checklist" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Background="Transparent" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=InspectionCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_ClickInspes">
                            <!--<I:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=InspectionCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </I:Interaction.Behaviors>-->
                        </MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Maintainence Plan" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" Background="Transparent"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
```

Xaml.cs Code for MenuFlyoutItem_ClickInspes:

```
private void MenuFlyoutItem_ClickInspes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(InpectionCheckListEquipmentPage));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to Bind selected Item values of MenuFlyoutItem to another page?

The [`Navigate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Animation_NavigationTransitionInfo_) method allows you to pass a parameter to be interpreted by the target of the navigation. Details for how to do please reference [Pass information between pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages#3-pass-information-between-pages). For example:

```
private void MenuFlyoutItem_ClickInspes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuFlyoutItem currentitem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(InpectionCheckListEquipmentPage),currentitem.Text);
}
```

And on the `InpectionCheckListEquipmentPage` :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter is string && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)e.Parameter))
    {
        var menuitemvalue = e.Parameter as string;
    }
    else
    {

    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```